# Asserting request made with GET/POST

Tags: javascript, zombie.js

I have a test setup using ZombieJS.

When clicking on a button in my page, I do a Ajax request to the backend, based on the current state of the page this could be a POST or a GET.

Is it possible, with ZombieJS to assert that a certain request was made, and if that request was a post or a get.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be best to call `getAttribute` on the form before submitting.

```
browser.query('#myform').getAttribute('method')
```

after submitting, you'd do `assert.ok(browser.success)`.